# Find groups match IN condition list incompletely

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm currently working on a stored procedure and I need to write a query, which selects **all** `GroupId`s that **don't have all** `TypeIds`.

Regarding this example:

```
Id | GroupId | TypeId |
---+---------+--------+
1  |  1      |  1     | 
2  |  1      |  2     |
3  |  1      |  3     |
4  |  2      |  1     | 
5  |  2      |  2     |
6  |  3      |  1     |
7  |  3      |  2     | 
8  |  3      |  3     |
9  |  4      |  2     |
```

I'd like to select `GroupId`s 2 and 4, because those groupes don't have all three `TypeId`s 1, 2 and 3. `GroupId` 4 only has `TypeId` 2 while `GroupId` 2 only has `TypeId`s 1 and 2.

My current query looks like this, but doesn't work:

```
SELECT [A].ActorPoolId
FROM [OfferCatalog].[Actor] [A]
WHERE [A].ActorTypeId IN ('1', '2', '3')
```

Do you know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can user a `group by` + `having` combination:

```
select [A].ActorPoolId
from [OfferCatalog].[Actor] [A]
where [A].ActorTypeId in ('1', '2', '3') 
group by [A].ActorPoolId 
having count(distinct [A].ActorTypeId) < 3
```

You can omit using `distinct` in case `ActorTypeId` is unique for each `ActorPoolId`.